# Real-time updates like Twitter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do you implement a real-time update like Twitter does ("423 more tweets since you started searching")?  I need to refresh my page at least every 10 seconds.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC and jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) javascript function which allows you to poll the server for updates at regular intervals using AJAX:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // This will be executed each 5s
    // TODO: query your server for updates probably using AJAX
    // example with jquery:
    $.getJSON('/arethereanyupdates', function(data) {
        if (data.isupdates) {
            alert('yeap there are updates');
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

There's also a push technology in HTML5 called [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) which allows the server to notify the client for updates but of course you will need an HTML5 compatible browser which nowadays is not difficult to find and a [WebSocket API](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) compliant server.

Comment: @Darin The tricky part with HTML5 Web Sockets these days isn't so much the browser, as finding a supporting server and software suite.

Comment: Thanks...so is this the standard way to do this?  Would it be better to implement some sort of caching to prevent the numerous hits to the DB?  Or is that over-kill?

Comment: @Matt, that's correct. I've seen some great Python implementations.

Comment: @Prabhu, if you use caching you won't know whether there are updates to the database :-) The caching should be done but with proper expiration policies.

Comment: @Matt, I prefer not to as I don't have sufficient experience. Just things that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an AJAX call to your server asking for updates, if the answer is positive (there are new things) you can show a javascript windows advising the user or just update the page content you need.

regards.

UPDATE: This [how-to](http://www.strangework.com/2007/07/17/asp-and-ajax-username-availability-check-example/) implements similar behavior

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of long-polling (aka COMET) support in todays browsers (this should, however, change soon, with HTML5), I'm polling the server every n seconds using AJAX request and sending the timestep of the latest visible entry/item/tweet/whatever. Then the backend count the number of newer items and returns it back to the browser.